# Parameter $r$ of Denavit-Hartenberg

Tags: forward-kinematics, dh-parameters

By watching this [video](http://youtu.be/rA9tm0gTln8) which explains how to calculate the classic Denavit–Hartenberg parameters of a kinematic chain, I was left with the impression that the parameter $r_i$ (or $a_i$) will always be positive.

Is this true? If not, could you give examples where it could be negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is true.  Although I don't have a formal proof.  I haven't read the original Denavit–Hartenberg paper, but this paper: "[Lipkin 2005: A Note on Denavit-Hartenberg Notation in Robotics](https://web.archive.org/web/20121119091715/http://profesores.usfq.edu.ec:80/laurents/IME440/DETC2005-85460_DenavitHartenberg.pdf)" explains the 3 main DH parameter conventions and how they differ.  It breaks down each of the 4 parameters into vector forms.  Specifically:

$$
a_2 = \vec{{O}_1 {O}_2} \cdot {x}_2
$$
Where $\vec{{O}_1 {O}_2}$ is the vector between the two frames.  The dot product *can* be negative, but only if the angle is greater than 90 degrees.  But because of the strict way you construct the frames, I don't think that can happen.

Comment: While a length is alway positive I think you define a link frame such that the distance to the next link frame was $-a$ or $-d$.

Comment: @PeterCorke, would it be possible for you to provide an example where the distances are negative?

Answer (score 1):

Parameter "r" or "a" is the link length of a robot's link which is a physical entity. And that can never be negative.

Answer (score 1):

It can be negative, because these parameters are then used to describe the transformations that are needed in order to convert one reference frame to another. For example:

[image: Reference frames]

So if we want to go from frame $i-1$ to frame $i$  we have to do the following:

- a rotation about $x_{i-1}$ for $a_{i-1}$ in order to make the $z$ axis parallel
- a transport in $x_{i-1}$ axis for $r_{i-1}$ in order to go to the $z_i$ axis
- a rotation about $z_i$ for $θ_{i}$ in order to make the $x$ axis parallel
- a transport in $z_{i}$ axis for $d_i$ in order to reach the origin of the $i$-th frame

Because all the transformations were done in relative frames, we multiply the homogenous transformations from the right.

So the transformation matrix is:

$$ T_i^{i-1} = Rot_x(a_{i-1}) Trans(r_{i-1}) Rot_z( θ_i) Trans (d_i) $$

**So the sign of the parameters are important.**

Also, another way to see it is how we use them in the Transformation Matrix:

$$ T = \begin{bmatrix} R_i^{i-1} & b^{i-1} \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

where $b^{i-1}$ is the vector in the $i-1$ frame that points to the origin of $i$. This vector is given (at least in the convention i use, taken from [craig's book](http://mathdep.ifmo.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/John-J.Craig-Introduction-to-Robotics-Mechanics-and-Control-3rd-edition-Pearson-Education-Inc.-2005.pdf) pg.83):

$$b^{i-1} = [r_{i-1} \ -sin(a_{i-1})d_i \ cos(a_{i-1})d_i]^T$$

For this vector, the sign of d_i is important. In the convention used by craig, you take the signed distance from $x_{i-1}$ to $x_i$.